# Top 2 Values in each Row Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a google sheet with 1006 rows which I am trying to use conditional formatting to identify the two top values across 7 columns (J to P) for each row.

I managed to get 1 row to work (highlighted in green) but I cannot replicate the conditional formatting across the other 1 005 rows.

The formula I used on row 9 was

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(OR(J9=LARGE($J$9:$P$9,{1,2})))
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with the absolute cell references? I would suggest trying (OR($J9=LARGE(...))) initially and make sure the range covers the lines required.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$J$9:$P$9
```

use

```
$J9:$P9
```

The above reference make referred columns to be absolute but rows are relative

Comment: beat me to it ;)